# What's wrong with my code? Error of "syntax error, unexpected elsif"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get below sintax error. But I have no idea what's wrong with this.

> SyntaxError in TagsController#index
> /app/models/tag.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected elsif elsif task["limit"] == 0 then ^~~~~

Someone gets this point?

```
if task["limit"] < 0 then
  deadCount++
elsif task["limit"] == 0 then
  todayCount++
elsif task["limit"] <= 3 then
  emerCount++
end
```

Comment: You are probably just confusing the parser, since Ruby has no pre/post increment/decrement operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no post/pre increment/decrement (++ / --) operator in Ruby and there is no need for `then` at the end of conditions

Try the below with `+=` operators:

```
if task["limit"] < 0
  deadCount += 1
elsif task["limit"] == 0
  todayCount += 1
elsif task["limit"] <= 3
  emerCount += 1
end
```